# Why setting "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to false before setting imageView, will show no images?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I am really new about iOS, I am learning about constraints in a scroll view.

I have the following code (type1):

```
wallpaper.view.translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
wallpaper.wallpaperImage = UIImage(named: backgroundImageName)
```

If I build the app, the screen only shows white screen.
I have checked `nil` possibility of my image but it's not.

Then I swapped the code into this (type2):

```
wallpaper.wallpaperImage = UIImage(named: backgroundImageName)
wallpaper.view.translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Then, the image would show up. My question is why does it affect my imageView?
I have seen several codes using type1 and they work normally.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is because the intrinsic content size of your the imageView while `image = nil` is `CGSize.zero` only if you define `width` and `height` constraint explicitly you will get a different result, then when you set the image before that the intrinsic content size of your `UIImageView` will have a value defined by the `UIImage` contained in the `UIImageView`

Comment: I have tried to add the intrinsic size both using placeholder and setting the initial image. If I use type 1, the image still won't show up. However, I checked the 'wallpaper.wallaperImageView.intrinsicContentSize', it returns 'nil'.

Comment: can you try adding the constraints for your UIImageView explicitly?

Comment: You are right @ReinierMelian, before setting the autolayout, my intrinsic size returns nil. I have put the image and intrinsic size placeholder in imageView, I don't understand why it still returns nil.

Comment: the intrinsic size placeholder is removed when app is in run time as is showed in storyboard `Setting a design time intrinsic content size only affects a view while editing in Interface Builder. The view will not have this intrinsic content size at runtime.`

Comment: I understand now, because I set the constraints using AutoLayout, before setting the `translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, my constraints are not used yet, thus the app can't determine my imageView size if I write the type 1 code. Thank you very much @ReinierMelian !

Comment: You got it!, @SwiftMage I am glad to help you, happy coding, and best regards